# Unhandled promise rejection - Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise, axios

I keep getthing this error and I am not sure what it mad about. I am using the latest version of FF and this code works in the latest version of Chrome and even Ie 11.

```
Unhandled promise rejection 
Error: Network Error
Stack trace:
createError@http://localhost:8080/main.js:6075:15
handleError@http://localhost:8080/main.js:5618:14

columnNumber: 15
​
config: Object { timeout: 5000, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​
fileName: "http://localhost:8080/main.js"
​
lineNumber: 6075
​
message: "Network Error"
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 5000, withCredentials: false, … }
​
response: undefined
​
stack: "createError@http://localhost:8080/main.js:6075:15\nhandleError@http://localhost:8080/main.js:5618:14\n"
​
    __proto__: Object { … }

    onUnhandled/</result<
es6.promise.js:101
./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_perform.js/module.exports
_perform.js:3:12
onUnhandled/<
es6.promise.js:95
./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_invoke.js/module.exports
_invoke.js:5
<anonymous>
_task.js:35
run
_task.js:21
listener
_task.js:25
```

This is the code where it is dying on

```
 login: flow(function*(email, password) {
  console.log("login")
  try {
    const response = yield self.rootStore().axios.post(
      "/tokens/auth", {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          grantType: "password",
      }
    );
    return response;
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e, "catch")
  }
}),
```

Seems like even though their is an error it is still calling my "then" and this causing issues(though still the underling issue of why there is a netwwork error when all other browser can go through)

```
 login(values.email, values.password).then((response) => {
            console.log("response", response); // this get called. Eventhough in the login flow function the error gets caught.
          }).catch(e => {console.log(e)})
```

Comment: Does `post()` return a Promise? If so, you should do `response.catch(error => { ... })`. If it does not, just wrap the code with try/catch, as `try { const response = ... } catch (error) { ... }`

Comment: I recommend you to read a about Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: I updated my code, but yes it does return a promise and it seems like an erorr was happening in the .then() I had though I thought it would not reach that code as I thought I only supplied the "resolved" function.  So this one issue I got to fix, but still it is not the root issue. "network issue" seems to be the root issue.

Comment: You are trying to reach "http://localhost:8080/main.js", is this a file or an end-point?

Comment: No that is the location that was set by webpack-serve. It is what is running my front end code. I should be hitting another localhost endpoint like localhost: https://localhost:44391/api  Could it be something because it is https?

Comment: Try to analyse your request in the Network section from the developer tools of your browser. Check the if the request is well formed and the status code of the response, if any, given by the server. Possible problems: if your application uses react or another framework and it is served on the same address of your API, there will be a conflict. If the API is in another address (like a diferent port), you should place the headers related to CORS to allow the request.

Comment: I think it has something to do with CORS and configuration of firefox for local host. I am not seeing a CORS warning and even this error now: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT   . Like I said it works on 2 different browsers so it probably is not code related.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a generator function.  Hopefully that's irrelevant to the problem.  You're `yield`ing the promise out rather than `await`ing it first?

Have you tried adding a `.catch(e => { console.log(e); })` or something to see what the rejection is?

Comment: I am using Mobx State tree, which has something called "flow" which acts like async/await and "yield" is equivalent to "await" . Let me see if catch gives me anything useful.

Comment: When there is the `await` behavior, the error is thrown from the place it was used and can be taken using try/catch.

Comment: The catch pretty much says the same thing "Network Error", though it still says it is unhandled in FF console.